# Custom CIFilter: CIKernel's sample() behaves strangely

Tags: ios, cifilter, glsles

I'm trying to figure out why the `sample(sampler img, vec2 coord)` method in a CIKernel I'm writing keeps giving me unexpected results, so I made simple test:

This works.

```
kernel vec4 simpleFilter(sampler p)
{
  vec2 dc = destCoord();
  return sample(p, samplerTransform(p, dc));
}
```

This does not. It produces `[0, 0, 0, 255]` for the first 255 pixels and then `[0, 0, 0, 0]` thereafter.

```
kernel vec4 simpleFilter(sampler p)
{
  vec2 dc = destCoord();
  vec2 tc = samplerTransform(p, dc);
  return sample(p, tc);
}
```

Why does the act of assigning the result of the sampler transform result to a `vec2` cause the whole process to break?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an artifact of using the Simulator rather than real hardware. Lesson learned: don't use simulator for custom CIFilter development.